# How to Add a Funnel chart in Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, charts, analytics

I am creating a Visualforce page and I have to add a funnel chart on the page. I am trying to add a similar chart like in dashboard. Tried for google chart but funnel chart is not available in google chart.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`<analytics:reportChart>`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) component.

First, create or customize a report to contain a funnel chart on it.  For example:

[image: report in report builder]

Then take the id of the report, which can be found in the URL, and set the reportId field of the `<analytics:reportChart>` element.

```
<apex:page >
  <analytics:reportChart reportId="00Oi0000005d5bW"/>
</apex:page>
```

It will result in a page that has the chart on it.  Make sure that your report is in a public folder.
[image: report in a Visualforce page]

Comment: Can't I add funnel chart without creating a report?

Comment: To use the `<analytics:reportChart>` component you must have a report that contains a chart. See [docs here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm).

Comment: But for this we need to create a report with funnel chart first then I can use it in visual force page. Can't I add this chart without creating a report.

Comment: No. There is no supported way to do that. You'd have to look at a third party charting package that has one or build your own and use that.

Answer (score 0):

hope this link will work for you.

http://revan03.blogspot.com/2014/01/custom-visualforce-dashboard.html

Thanks
IRaj

Comment: This link is using high chart. But high chart is not an open source for a profitable organization , So implementation with this solution is not an good idea.